# how to serialize map of vector with map value

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, serialization, boost

I'm trying to use a boost to serialize this data type:

```
map <vector<vector<char>>, map <char, int>>
```

but I have a hard time finding out how to serialize it. what I'm trying to do is to save this variable because it's an answer to a training model then load it. if there another method to save this variable to file then read it no problem

Answer (score 0):

Many ways, but since you tagged boost:

**Live On Coliru**

```
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using TrainingModel =
    std::map<std::vector<std::vector<char>>, std::map<char, int>>;

void save(std::string filename, TrainingModel const& model) {
    std::ofstream ofs(filename);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << model;
}

TrainingModel load(std::string filename) {
    TrainingModel model;
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> model;
    return model;
}

int main() {
    TrainingModel model{
        {{{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e', 'f'}}, {{'A', 1}, {'B', 2}}},
        {{{'g', 'h', 'i'}, {'j', 'k', 'l'}}, {{'G', 7}, {'H', 8}}},
        {{{'m', 'n', 'o'}, {'p', 'q', 'r'}}, {{'M', 13}, {'N', 14}}},
    };

    save("model.dat", model);
    TrainingModel cloned = load("model.dat");

    std::cout << "Clone equal? " << std::boolalpha << (model == cloned) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Clone equal? true
```